# Chaining Lambdas - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on a problem from the Kotlin Apprentice book in the Lambdas chapter.  Here is the problem:

> Using the same nameList list, first filter the list to contain only names which
> have more than four characters in them, and then create the same concatenation
> of names as in the above exercise. (Hint: you can chain these operations
> together.)

How can I chain the two lambdas together?  Below is my code with separate lines for the 2 lambdas.

```
fun main() {
val nameList = listOf("John", "Jacob", "Jingleheimer", "Schmidt")
val onlyLongNames = nameList.filter {it.length > 4}
val myNameToo = onlyLongNames.fold("") {a, b -> a + b}
println(myNameToo)
}
```

Comment: chain means u can call function after function in one flow, without the need of creating extra variables. So here `nameList.filter {it.length > 4}.fold("") {a, b -> a + b}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  fun main() {
    val nameList = listOf("John", "Jacob", "Jingleheimer", "Schmidt")
    val myNameToo = nameList.filter {it.length > 4}.fold("") {a, b -> a + b}
    println(myNameToo)
    }
```